# data format changes when linking data to shapes in visio

Tags: excel, visio

I'm linking data from excel to shapes in Visio using basic numbering. I've formatted the numbers in excel to show 2 decimal places on every cell but when the spreadsheet is uploaded into Visio, the cells that end in a 0 get removed. This is a problem because it wont distinguish 1.1 with 1.10.

Any ideas on how to format on the Visio side to properly show the shape number?

[Screenshot of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgKHo.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the rare situations when you cannot treat numbers as true numbers. They have to be text-that-look-like-numbers.

You want an ordinal system that sequences 1, 1.1, 1.2, ... 1.10, 1.11. That isn't going to happen with true numbers. They have to be text.

```
=TEXT(1.1, "0.0")    '<~~ 1.1
=TEXT(1.1, "0.00")   '<~~ 1.10
```

The only way you are going to retain your organizational system is to treat them all as text. Sorting will have to be manipulated with a 'helper' column or custom sort.